# Populating JList from database SQL

Tags: java, sql, swing, jdbc, jcombobox

I have been trying to populate a dropdown list with information that exsists in my database but have failed miserably.
I have seen multiple guides and there have been some successful codes which i have not been able to copy since i am a novice and have likely missed some step.
This is what i am currently trying:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class populategui extends JFrame
{
    private JComboBox box;
    private JLabel picture;
    private static String[ ] filename = {rs.next};

    {
        try
    {        
            Class.forName(com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver);
            Connection con = (Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=LIVE;integratedsecurity=true");
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            String query="SELECT TOP(10)*FROM ERIT";
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
            while(rs.next());
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {  
    }
    };

            public populategui(){
                super ("the title");
                setLayout(new FlowLayout());
                box=new JComboBox(filename);


            }

    }
```

If u need more information please let me know.

Comment: There's not really enough in here to go on.  Does it compile?  Does it run?  Is there an exception?  If so, what's the stack trace?

Comment: it is supposed to compile a dropdown list of information located in the database...
it runs on NetBeans and operates MS SQL... and i dont know what you mean by stack trace im sorry

Comment: @NeedyHelpo - no that is NOT what he means: see my Answer.

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: <any>
 at populategui.<init>(populategui.java:25)
 at apple.main(populatetable.java:5)

Answer (score 1):

Part of your problem is that you are "squashing" the exceptions that might tell you what the problem.  Change it to this (at least):

```
try {
    ...
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

so that you can see what exception is being thrown...

Better still, log the exception.

---

As a general rule, it is a bad idea to catch `java.lang.Exception`, because you could end up catching all sorts of exceptions that you haven't anticipated.  And it is a TERRIBLE idea catch exceptions and just continue as if nothing had gone wrong.  It makes it difficult to figure out why your program doesn't work if you throw away the key evidence.

---

Finally, it seems like you are trying write Java code by copy-and-pasting examples you've found on the internet.  This is a recipe for writing unreliable code.  You need to *learn* the language properly,  Go buy and read a good textbook on Java programming, or take the (free) Oracle Java Tutorial.

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: <any>
 at populategui.<init>(populategui.java:25)
 at apple.main(populatetable.java:5)

Comment: @NeedyHelpo - so ... did you read the error message?  Does the phrase "uncompilable source code" mean something to you?  If not, you need to take the time to do Oracle Java Tutorial!

Answer (score 0):

I think you main-problem ist to no-op in you loop:

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
while(rs.next());
```

That code is expandet:

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
while(rs.next()){
// nothing to to (n-times)
}
```